# View current inserts from a connection into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to view the current connections making an insert into a table?

I know about `sp_who2`, is there any in which the current connection can be tied to a database insert or update?

Answer (score 1):

One can use SQL profiler to monitor all the operations made by a connection/clientid/process id.
Go to Tools --> SQl Profiler
and from there you can select the performance counters like:
SQL Statements completed, etc.
Capture the trace.

I would strongly suggest **not to run** SQL profiler on a production machine though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you need sufficient permissions):

```
DECLARE @sqltext VARBINARY(128)
SELECT @sqltext = sql_handle
FROM sys.sysprocesses
WHERE spid = 61                -- Specify your SPID here
SELECT TEXT
FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(@sqltext)
```